# Edge cases for deep copy of an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, deep-copy

I'm trying to make a deep copy of an object without using **lodash**.

I'm unable to think of any case where this will fail. Can someone suggest me any edge case where this may fail?

```js
let Obj = {
  a: "Hello",
  b: {
    c: {
      h: "World"
    },
    d: null
  },
  e: () => 'me',
  f: new Date(),
  g: [1, 2, 3]
}

let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Obj));
for (let key in Obj) {
  if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key) || Obj[key] instanceof Date) {
    result[key] = Obj[key];
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Circular references will fail with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: @Pointy Example?

Comment: If two properties of an object refer to the same object value, the result will contain shallow copies. If a property of an object refers directly or indirectly back to the object being serialized, the `.stringify()` will fail. Deep copying, in general, is a very hard problem with no general solution.

Comment: Also if the target object has references to things like DOM nodes or other "exotic" object values, it won't work.

Comment: @Pointy It doesn't work in case of circular references. Can you elaborate on "exotic" object values.

Comment: Lodash is 100% obsolete today. Every Lodash "helpers" can be coded in native JS better. In your case just use [structuredClone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone). It can handle circular references, too.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will also fail for objects like [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and it has very poor performance (large objects can be deep cloned much faster).

Comment: "exotic" objects are things that are provided to the JavaScript context by the runtime wrapper. DOM elements are a really good example. They're not really JavaScript objects, but for most purposes they *look* like JavaScript objects.

Comment: @Pointy Very few "clone" implementations I've seen can accurately deep-copy DOM nodes, so I wouldn't put too much importance on this. It's rarely needed.